# How to extend Database Log Report from Contact

Tags: civireport

I would like to extend standard functionality of Database Log Report generated from contact.

For now there is list of standard colums, but there is no information about what changes was made in fields. Only interactions are tracked.
I would like to have report, which will show me changes on fields, eg changes in email address.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/logging/

But oddly that page just explains it and doesn't say how to turn it on. You go to Administer - System Settings - Misc and then turn on logging.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've missed this part before. This change solved my problem partially. Now, I can see details of change, but it is not displayed in report.

Comment: I cannot edit first one

Thanks for that. I've missed this part before. This change solved my problem partially. Now, I can see details of change, but it is not displayed in report.

Contact Logging Report (Summary) is workign fine, but there are no details of change exported to PDF/CSV.

Whe I try to use Contact Logging Report (Detail) i've got information that This report can not be displayed because there are no entries in the logging tables yet. I've checked SQL adn there are no log tables. Is this one must be configured in other place?

Comment: Detail report isn't a standalone report unless you manually enter url parameters. You get to it by clicking Update for a particular row from the summary report, so that it knows which detail you want.